How to run tensorflow lite on Flutter
An error occurs during startup and it does not work. Are you doing it wrong when using Tensorflow lite?
Interpreter? interpreter;
List<Map<String, dynamic>> selectedAnswers = [];
List characters = ['ENFP', 'ISFP', 'INFJ', 'ISTP', 'ENFJ', 'INTJ', 'ENTI', 'ESFP', 'INFP', 'INTP', 'ISTI', 'ENTP', 'ISFJ', 'ESTI', 'ESTP', 'ESFJ'];
List X_test_custom = [0,0,2,-1,-1,2,-1,0,2,0,0,1,0,-1,1,0,0,-1,1,0,0,2,0,-1,0,-1,2,0,2,0,0,0,1,0,-1,1,0,2,0,-2,-2,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,-1,0,0,-1,0,1,0,0,1,-1,2];
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
fetchQuestions();
loadModel();
}
Future<void> loadModel() async {
  try {
    final interpreter = await Interpreter.fromAsset('assets/myPersonalityModel.tflite');
    print('Model loaded');
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error: $e');
  }
}
List<int> padSequences(List<int> inputData, int maxLen) {
  if (inputData.length >= maxLen) {
    return inputData.sublist(0, maxLen);
  } else {
    return List<int>.filled(maxLen - inputData.length, 0)..setAll(0, inputData);
  }
}


Future<String> predictCharacter(List<int> inputData) async {
try {
  final interpreter = await Interpreter.fromAsset('assets/myPersonalityModel.tflite');
  final isolateInterpreter = await IsolateInterpreter.create(address: interpreter.address);

  if (inputData.isEmpty) {
    return 'Input data is empty';
  }

  if (interpreter == null) {
    return 'Model not loaded';
  }

  final paddedInput = padSequences(inputData, 60);
  final input = paddedInput.map((e) => e.toDouble()).toList();

  var inputBuffer = Float32List.fromList(input);

  var outputBuffer = List<double>.filled(1, 0);

  isolateInterpreter.run(inputBuffer, outputBuffer);
  print(outputBuffer);
  final predictedIndex = outputBuffer[0].toInt();
  return characters[predictedIndex];
} catch (e) {
  print('Error: $e');
  return "Prediction failed";
}

}
The following error occurs when running:
flutter: Model loaded
flutter: Predicted Character: Instance of 'Future<String>'
flutter: [0.0]
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception:           LateInitializationError: Field '_sendPort@316391573' has not been initialized.
 #0      IsolateInterpreter._sendPort (package:tflite_flutter/src/isolate_interpreter.dart)
 #1      IsolateInterpreter.runForMultipleInputs     (package:tflite_flutter/src/isolate_interpreter.dart:122:5)  
 #2      IsolateInterpreter.run (package:tflite_flutter/src/isolate_interpreter.dart:106:12)
 #3      _QuestionPageState.predictCharacter (package:humun/screens/QuestionPage.dart:81:24)
<asynchronous suspension>

How to fix?

You might update your title to the actual question and not an explanation of why you are needing help.  This will help people find the question to assist you.

I'm not an expert with flutter or tensorflow, but it looks like you need to initialize sendPort

The bots said the same thing, so def look into that ^.  Plus the error message indicates as much : _sendPort@316391573' has not been initialized .


Why do you load the model twice? Once in loadModel() and another time in predictCharacter().
This is a common issue. It takes some time to initialize the IsolateInterpreter. Add a await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1)); after final isolateInterpreter = await IsolateInterpreter.create(address: interpreter.address); line.

